# Problem with ADA file executed by a c++(UsrAppInit) in VXWorks 6.7(workspace-4)?

Tags: c++, macros, ada, vxworks

I have a file build and compiled correctly in ADA (a simple Hello world). I want to execute the file .o from a c++ using taskspawn. To do that I have read that you must declare in the c++  something like that:

...

```
#include <taskLib.h>

/* Ada binder-generated main - ADA_MAIN is passed as a macro from the makefile */

extern void ADA_MAIN(void);

void UsrAppInit()

{

int stackSize = 0x80000;


int spawnFlags = VX_FP_TASK;

/* MAIN_TASK_NAME is passed as a macro from the makefile */
char * mainTaskName = (char *) MAIN_TASK_NAME;

int priority = 100;

/* Spawn Ada environment task */

taskSpawn(mainTaskName, priority, spawnFlags, stackSize,
(FUNCPTR) ADA_MAIN, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
}
```

to complete the process I have declared the ADA_MAIN as a MACRO in makefile (in my case the makefile is makefile.mk)

(MAIN_ADA  pathOfmyADAexe and MAIN_TASK_NAME "the procedure of the helloworld")

but the MACRO are not recognized in the process so I have error in compilation for MAIN_TASK_NAME and ADA_MAIN. Any suggestion about how am I missing? I could also do in different way but how?

Comment: You haven't written which Ada compiler you are using but assuming it's GNAT the C/C++ application must first call adainit Before any call to an Ada subprogram and the last action of the C/C++ application is to call adafinal. Maybe these calls are hidden in the ADA_MAIN macro mentioned above? https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Binding-with-Non-Ada-Main-Programs.html

Comment: If your compiler is GNAT, I’ll attempt an answer. If not, go to your compiler manuals/vendor.

Comment: If you think there’s something wrong with your macro (why do you capitalise it?) you should add it to your question.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, the Ada compiler is GNAT PRO 18.2. the Macro are capitalized according to the example that I see on-line. adainit() and adafinal are not recognized during the building procedure.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know about your `ADA_MAIN`, and you don't tell us what your `MACRO` is, so it's a little hard to talk about them. Also, it's a while since I used VxWorks (and, then, we were supported, so had access to a cross-compiler that did the build for us: and our main program was in Ada).

That said, your problem comes down to [building a program with Ada components where the main program isn't in Ada](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Binding-with-Non-Ada-Main-Programs.html#Binding-with-Non-Ada-Main-Programs).

Ada programs need *elaboration*. This is the process that calls in all the components of the runtime library and arranges for them to be initialized in the right order. What components, you ask? well, for instance, there's the obvious `Ada.Text_IO`; and there's the less-obvious things, such as exception handling.

The elaboration code is generated using *gnatbind*.

Given this `hello.adb`

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Hello is
begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("hello!");
end Hello;
```

you really need to supply a specification, as otherwise the compiler will generate a linker name such as `__ada_hello`; take control by `hello.ads`,

```
procedure Hello with
  Export,
  Convention => C,
  External_Name => "hello";
```

You'll be using a cross-compilation suite. The components are prefixed by the target name, e.g. `powerpc-wrs-vxworks-gnatmake`, `arm-eabi-gnatbind`, but I'll just use the bare component name below.

```
$ gnatmake -c hello.adb
```

which generates `hello.o`, `hello.ali` (if the program was more complicated, it'd compile the closure too).

Now bind:

```
$ gnatbind -n -Lhello -static hello.ali
```

where

- `-n` : main program not in Ada
- `-Lhello`: `adainit`, `adafinal` renamed `helloinit`, `hellofinal`
- `-static`: pretty sure VxWorks doesn't support shared libraries?

generating `b~hello.ads`, `b~hello.adb` (depending on the compiler release, the `~` may be replaced by e.g. double underscore). Compile:

```
$ gnatmake -c b~hello.adb
```

Now, to call from C++. you need to tell the compiler about the symbols in the Ada code, in e.g. `hello.h`:

```
extern "C" {
  void helloinit();
  void hellofinal();
  void hello();
}
```

and then the main program in `main.cc`:

```
#include "hello.h"

int main() {
  helloinit();
  hello();
  hellofinal();
}
```

which leaves you with the C++ compile and link, which needs the Ada runtime in `libgnat.a` and (for tasking) `libgnarl.a`, and is of course very compiler- and installation-specific: here, on the macOS host, I used

```
$ g++ main.cc b~hello.o hello.o /opt/gcc-8.1.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15/8.1.0/adalib/libgnat.a
$ ./a.out
hello!
```

---

Translating this to the VxWorks context, I'd say that you'd call `helloinit()` from your main program (you probably won't need `hellofinal()`), and pass `hello` to `taskSpawn()` in place of your `ADA_MAIN`.